# How to get path of a document using sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am using an document management application which uses SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to fetch document names along with its path. For example,

If my document name is test.txt and it is under folder structure A/B/C, my output should be A/B/C/test.txt.

Could anyone please help me with a query?

Table name: DTree

DataId     Name
=======  ========

12345     test.txt

Comment: so you using `FileTable` or what?

Answer (score 0):

If the folder structure is not in the database, or you don't have a mechanism to tell SQL what the file path is, I don't think you can do this.

You could have a file named test.txt in every single folder, so you will need to have the file path explicitly.  If the file path is stored in that table as A/B/C, you can just concatenate the file path with the file name like

```
SELECT filepath + '/' + filename
```